# Take tokens from a text file, calculate their frequency, and return them in a new text file in Python

Tags: python, text-files, token, word-frequency

After a long time researching and asking friends, I am still a dumb-dumb and don't know how to solve this.

So, for homework, we are supposed to define a function which accesses two files, the first of which is a text file with the following sentence, from which we are to calculate the word frequencies:

> In a Berlin divided by the Berlin Wall , two angels , Damiel and Cassiel , watch the city , unseen and unheard by its human inhabitants .

We are also to include commas and periods: each single item has already been tokenised (individual items are surrounded by whitespaces - including the commas and periods). Then, the word frequencies must be entered into a new txt-file as "word:count", and in the order in which the words appear, i.e.:

> In:1
>   
>  a:1
>   
>  Berlin:2
>   
>  divided:1

etc.

I have tried the following:

```
def find_token_frequency(x, y):
    with open(x, encoding='utf-8') as fobj_1:
        with open(y, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fobj_2:
            fobj_1list = fobj_1.split()
            unique_string = []
            for i in fobj_1list:
                if i not in unique_string:
                    unique_string.append(i)
            for i in range(0, len(unique_string)):
                fobj_2.write("{}: {}".format(unique_string[i], fobj_1list.count(unique_string[i])))
```

I am not sure I need to actually use `.split()` at all, but I don't know what else to do, and it does not work anyway, since it tells me I cannot split that object.

I am told:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]

fobj_1list = fobj_1.split()

AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'
```

When I remove the .split(), the displayed error is:

```
fobj_2.write("{}: {}".format(unique_string[i], fobj_1list.count(unique_string[i])))

AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Comment: Divide this problem into two separate pieces: first, forget about writing wordcounts to fobj_2, just get the wordcounts working internally. Edit your question to **show us the exact output you currently get, and precisely why it's wrong, instead of just saying " it does not work anyway"**.

Comment: **Instead of saying *"it tells me I cannot split that object"*, post us the exact traceback, showing which line of code, and which 'object' you're talking about**. Next, try to figure out why the `s.split()` method doesn't exist on that object (Hint: look at its `type()` Is it a list? tuple? string? something else?)

Comment: Also, it's going to be a lot easier to temporarily debug if you strip the function `def` line and the `with` context objects, we don't even need `f_obj2`, and you can imperatively declare `fobj_1 = open(x, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Are you guys allowed use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) yet? Or else, a simple list or dict is fine.

Comment: You need to do fobj_1.read(). Also, I'd suggest using collections.Counter.

Comment: And when you declare a list called `unique_string`, that's a strong hint that you should actually use a `dict` rather than a `list`. Then you don't need the "Look-Before-You-Leap" check `if i not in unique_string: ...`. Oh and don't call your variable `i` if it's supposed to be a word or a token, call it something obvious like `word`. Usuaully we use `i, j, k` for integers.

Comment: Do what Samuel wrote below, except add in the unique_list ordered array and traverse that to retrieve from the frequency dictionary, for the final report. So, 'for word in unique_list' rather than 'for word in frequency'.

Answer (score 2):

Let's divide your problem into smaller problems so we can more easily solve this.
First we need to read a file, so let's do so and save it into a variable:

```py
with open("myfile.txt") as fobj_1:
    sentences = fobj_1.read()
```

Ok, so now we have your file as a string stored in sentences. Let's turn it into a list and count the occurrence of each word:

```py
words = sentence.split(" ")
frequency = {word:words.count(word) for word in set(words)}
```

Here frequency is a dictionary where each word in the sentences is a key with the value being how many times they appear on the sentence. Note the usage of `set(words)`. A set does not have repeated elements, that's why we are iterating over the set of words and not the word list.
Finally, we can save the word frequencies into a file

```py
with open("results.txt", 'w') as fobj_2:
    for word in frequency: fobj_2.write(f"{word}:{frequency[word]}\n")
```

Here we use f strings to format each line into the desired output. Note that f-strings are available for python3.6+.

Comment: Your solution has given me a word count, but count in the TXT-file was not produced in the order of the words found in the original TXT-file. I achieved this by modifying your suggested code thus: `frequency = {word:words.count(word) for word in words}`, however, while this does sort the problem with the order in which the words and their frequencies appear, the data I get looks like this (without line breaks):
Classic:{'Classic': 1, 'Short': 1, 'Stories': 1, 'Logo\nWas': 1,

instead of (think with line breaks):
Classic:1
Short:1
Stories:1
Logo:1
Was:3

Comment: What you did worked fine here on python 3.7. Which python version are you using?

Comment: This is the code I ran: `frequency = {word:words.count(word) for word in words}`,`with open("results.txt", 'w') as fobj_2: for word in frequency: fobj_2.write(f"{word}:{frequency[word]}\n")`

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to comment as I don't have the required reputation, but the reason `split()` isn't working is because you're calling it on the file object itself, not a string. Try calling:

```
fobj_1list = fobj_1.readline().split()
```

instead. Also, when I ran this locally, I got an error saying that `TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`. You may want to remove the encoding argument from your function calls.

I think that should be enough to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

The following script should do what you want.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3


def find_token_frequency(inputFileName, outputFileName):

    # wordOrderList to maintain order
    # dict to keep track of count
    wordOrderList = []
    wordCountDict = dict()

    # read the file 
    inputFile = open(inputFileName, encoding='utf-8')
    lines = inputFile.readlines()
    inputFile.close()

    # iterate over all lines in the file
    for line in lines:
        # and split them into words
        words = line.split()

        # now, iterate over all words
        for word in words:
            # and add them to the list and dict
            if word not in wordOrderList:
                wordOrderList.append(word)
                wordCountDict[word] = 1
            else:
                # or increment their count
                wordCountDict[word] = wordCountDict[word] +1


    # store result in outputFile
    outputFile = open(outputFileName, 'w', encoding='utf-8') 
    for index in range(0, len(wordOrderList)):
        word = wordOrderList[index]
        outputFile.write(f'{word}:{wordCountDict[word]}\n')

    outputFile.close()

find_token_frequency("input.txt", "output.txt")
```

I changed your variable names a bit to make the code more readable.